# Mariadb database trigger before insert fails if field value is null

Tags: triggers, mariadb

I am trying to capture (audit) when an insert is performed on a table, using a database trigger.  The insert does not process when one of the fields is null.  I have proven this(to myself) by removing the null column from the insert.

If the data in `NEW.col2` is NULL the insert in example 1 does not execute, when I remove `col2`, as in example 2,  from the insert, it works.

example 1 - `insert into table_a (col1,col2,col3) values (NEW.col1,NEW.col2,NEW.col3);`

example 2 - `insert into table_a (col1,col3) values (NEW.col1,NEW.col3);`

why does it not work and what do i do to get past this?

I am aware of other ways to accomplish this task, but this is the solution we need to use - database trigger / capture insert.

Comment: Is `col2` declared `NOT NULL DEFAULT xxx`? that could account for it

Comment: No, it allows null.  The field being inserted must have a value or the NEW.field causing an issue.  The must be a way to use the NEW.field even when the value is null

Comment: Could `...values (NEW.col1, COALESCE(NEW.col2, 0), NEW.col3);` work as an alternative? ... instead of 0 (the second parameter), could be any value that the column supports. The [docs on coalesce](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/coalesce/) if not familiar.

Comment: @mike don't edit your post with your solution. Instead, post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around --- I was able to get this to work by adding IFNULL to all columns -> IFNULL(NEW.col2,'NULL'). Seem to me to be extra work, BUT it is working now.